# Coil and Core-What exactly this is?

Tags: measurement, coil, core

Im learning about electrical measuring instruments(PMMC).In this textbook it is said that a rectangular coil is wound on a aluminium former.Inside which there is an iron core.

My question is what exactly is a core?Isn't it the thing on which the coil is wound on?
How can the coil be rectangular(isn't it wire's).Question might sound stupid,but please give some explanation.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a view from a different angle.

[image]

From the [Wiki article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galvanometer#History) on galvanometers.

Now you can see that the coil is wound on a lightweight rectangular former, with a bearing in the centre of each end, and this former is suspended between the poles of a U-shaped magnet (broken open in the image to show the coil).

Now there's a huge gap between the magnet's pole pieces which would result in a weak magnetic field, and a very insensitive meter. So the trick is to fill that gap with a fixed iron core, such that there are two very narrow gaps, just wide enough for the former and its coil.

This concentrates the magnetic field in those gaps, and the magnet pole pieces are shaped to linearise it (it should be the same at any angle where the former is in the gap).

The iron core is fixed - if it moved with the coil, its weight would slow down the meter movement. But because it's inside the former, the former cannot make a full revolution, it would hit the core's supports. So this is a great arrangement for a meter, but no good for a rotating motor.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and posting image.But the picture itself is confusing to me.Could you answer to my comment on the first answer

Comment: The point is that the iron core is _fixed_ and does not rotate. To give the coil some mechanical stability, it is wound around a rectangular shaped frame, the former. This former must not be magnetic, so copper, aluminum, plastic etc. is suitable.

Comment: There is no question in that comment to answer.

Comment: @sweber Okay,so the cylindrical thing in the figure above is the iron core?And the frame surrounding that is the former on which the wires are wound.

Comment: Yes, the rectangular thing running around the cylinder is the former, and it is free to rotate.

Comment: @BrianDrummond okay.. now i got it

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding this correctly, here's how you might think of it.

Take a piece of wire. Straighten it out, then bend it three times to make a square. The two ends should be touching. You now have a rectangular (square) coil of 1 turn. Use a longer wire, and stack the squares on top of each other, and now you have a rectangular coil. Equivalently, if you took a cylindrical chunk of metal (the core/former), and wrapped a wire around it from top to bottom multiple times, you'd also have a rectangular coil of wire. Put the whole thing inside a big permanent magnet, and you have your motor.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.But from your asnwer i can see that the former/core is the same thing.But if you look at the text,it says that the rectangular coil is wound over a former of aluminium or copper and inside there is a iron core.So the text says like the former and core are 2 different things